# WP_Query meta_query AND relationship doesn't return result

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query with two filters:
`setupfee_ipcenter` and `cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new`
for some reason when I use both arrays it doesn't return any post,  and I definitely have a post with values, see db image below.

Each of the queries works great on its own.

What is the opposite of `IN` for the compare value? For example if the value in the second array is empty, then select all values that are not empty?

This is the query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'ipcenters',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',     
    //  'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query'     =>  array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'setupfee_ipcenter',
                'value'     => 30,
                'compare'   => =,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new',
                'value'     =>  array('0-50', '51-100'),
                'compare'   => 'IN',

            )
        ),
    );


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This is the query var dump, at least a part of it:

```
    object(WP_Query)#7690 (50) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(9) "ipcenters"
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["meta_query"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(17) "setupfee_ipcenter"
        ["value"]=>
        string(2) "30"
        ["compare"]=>
        string(1) "="
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(34) "cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new"
        ["value"]=>
       array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "51-100"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "0-50"
    }
        ["compare"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
      }
    }
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(65) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(9) "ipcenters"
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["meta_query"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(17) "setupfee_ipcenter"
        ["value"]=>
        string(2) "30"
        ["compare"]=>
        string(1) "="
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(34) "cost_per_month_ipcenter_filter_new"
        ["value"]=>
       array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "51-100"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "0-50"
       }
        ["compare"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
      }
    }
```

Here is the image from the db with the post `3882` data:

[image]

Comment: You need to put quotes around the `=` in your first meta query array and you might want to add `'type' => 'numeric'` to the first array as well.  For your second question, I believe you can use `EXISTS`, which will select anything that has a value.

Comment: Thanks, I have another small question. for example, if the value (the array )in the second array is empty and I want to retrieve all data, how can I do it? what do I need to write as the compare value? let's say the user wants to filter only by the first array even if it dosent have a value in the second array. for example, for the first array compare I have a function that checks if there is a value in the url and by that the compare sign is changed form `=` to `!=`.

Comment: You use `EXISTS`.